# Azure Active Directory Domains

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, cloud

I would like to know if Azure Active Directory support accounts outside the defined domain.
I’m trying to grant access to users that already have their own personal accounts but it seems that it is not supported.

Comment: please better describe your problem and what you mean by `outside described domain`. WAAD has a feature called "Application Access Enhancements", which allows a SSO (Single-Sign-On) with more than 500 SaaS solutions (such as SalesFore, Google just to name a few) - http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/11/21/app-access-enhancements-ga-azure-ad-premium-preview.aspx is this something you are looking for, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Azure AD does not yet have a custom user store.  The users would be source from Windows Azure AD or an on-premises Windows Server AD.

Alternatively, you may be able to leverage Windows Azure AD ACS (Access Control Service) as a way to federate with social providers like Google, Windows Live / Microsoft Account, Yahoo, etc.

Comment: The Correct Documentation for the latter part of this answer would be: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-create-users/  - (There is also an option in the Directory Configuration page to control the addition of the Guest Users)

Answer (score 0):

A user in a directory can be sourced from either a directory in Azure AD, which is referred to as a Work or Student Account (previously called an Organizational Account). Or, the user can be sourced from a Microsoft Account. An example of how this may look in the Azure AD Users page of the Azure Management Portal is shown here.

[Azure Active Directory Portal Example](http://justazure.com/azure-active-directory-part-1-introduction/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NullReferenceException: Technically, this does seem to answer the question in the affirmative.